# How to join multiple paths of the same object?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, cs6, path

I have traced an icon from a png in illustrator; I had to fix the rough edges and ended up with this shape:

[image]

I'm using Fill set to black and Stroke set to nothing. Everytime I try joing the four lower points, all of my shape turns into black. Even if both end points are joined properly.

Comment: I'm not really certain how anyone here could answer this. Check the paths,.. the joins... the fills, check for compound paths, clipping masks, etc.

Comment: Which two lower points?

Comment: Sorry, 4 lower points. This shape is supposed to be a Stopwatch.

Comment: I hope you plan to clean up the proportions on this thing a bit! haha the disproportional dimensions of this make my eyes hurt.

Comment: Hahaha, indeed. You can blame the tracing tool. I just needed to close the last gape before cleaning up the proportions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to separate inner and outer "circle" and Exlude them with Pathfinder tool. If you cant  see the light gray shape, you have it below the dark gray object.

*Before Exclusion — two objects:*

[image: before Exclusion — two objects]

*After exclusion — one object:*

[image: after exclusion — one object]

Comment: That's it. If I close the points, I'll have 2 separated "circles". Thanks.

Comment: Hi mahish, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!